# Ubuntu 15.04 Wifi keeps disconneting randomly

Tags: wireless, 15.04

Im new to ubuntu 15.04 and I have it dual booted on 2012 mac. I have been having problems with the network disconnecting repeatedly. I have to disable the network and enable it for my wifi to work again.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit] your question adding the make/model of your WiFi adapter and the driver you are using. These commands can prove helpful for that: `lspci`, `sudo lshw -c network`, `lsmod`. Also check *Software & Updates* -> *Additional drivers* for proprietary drivers for your WiFi.